# laravel app.js very large file size

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I have deployed a Laravel 5.3 application to Heroku. However, when loading /login, I noticed a very slow page load time. The problem seems to be a very large `app.js` file: `/js/app.js`. Here is a screenshot of the Network resource panel in DevTools: [screenshot- Network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3bbD.png). The 3rd resource from the top is the offending file.

I am not sure why this file has gotten so large. here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/AshMenhennett/Salon-Pricing.

I wasn't able to post anymore links, so do let me know if you would like direct links to specific files.

What should I be doing to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Link to the offending file: https://beauty-salon-pricing.herokuapp.com/js/app.js

Comment: Your file is bundling a large number of libraries into 1 file but the main offender I see is that you are including source maps within the .js file. Try moving some of the library files into their own file, and remove the source maps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the looks of your link you've not created a production version of your assets, and currently all the source maps are in your `app.js` file, which will be adding a lot of the file size, the css and js output are also not compress/minified either.

Assuming you're using laravel elixir, you just need to run `gulp --production` and this will remove the source maps, compress the js and css outputs, etc.

Comment: @wader i am also having a similar issue but in my case i have run 'gulp --production' but my app.js file is still as large as 600kb...pls what can i do to solve it ?

Answer (score 12):

The most obvious thing you can do is to run `npm run prod`. This will compile the assets for production use. But in most cases, you must be looking at other solutions beyond running `npm run prod`. If your production file is too large, you must check your dependencies. Remove unnecessary dependencies and ensure that you don't use a lot of external libraries. For example, if you are using bootstrap, you should rely on Bootstrap's alerts in order to show alerts rather than using a Vue package to show alerts. I admit that sometimes you will need to use an external library to make your website interactive but to achieve that, you will have to sacrifice the performance. So your best bet in order to reduce the app.js file is to use the minimal external dependencies in your package.json.

The second thing you can do is use minimum HTML in your components' templates. A lot of components with heavy HTML/CSS will contribute to a larger app.js file. This is yet another approach that will result in a smaller app.js file.

Lastly, you should consider using Vue's [component slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) to pass HTML contents to your components. This will leave the HTML in your static files and only javascript data (API calls, props, etc.) will be compiled in the app.js file. This is an effective approach to build a smaller app.js file.

Edit: You can remove JQuery and Bootstrap scripts from the bootstrap.js file and can include these dependencies separately. It is always a good idea to have a few more scripts rather than having a very large script. i.e. browsers do parallel downloading and thus using JQuery and Bootstrap dependencies separately is a good idea.

Comment: Should be marked as the answer. This addresses the build problem as well as practical ways to further reduce the actual contents of the file.

Answer (score 6):

You need to **load the components asynchronously**

Webpack has an awesome feature to create chunks of code. The key to this is to use async components. These components get loaded completely asynchronously whenever the component is present on the page you just loaded.

**Let's do it.**

In `resources/js/app.js`.

I changed:

```
Vue.component('jobs', require('./pages/employer/jobs/Index.vue').default);
```

to:

```
Vue.component('jobs', () => import('./pages/employer/jobs/Index.vue'));
```

and in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output:{
        chunkFilename:'js/vuejs_code_split/[name].js',
    }
});
```

Now by running `npm run watch or prod` each component file is saved `public/js/vuejs_code_split/[name].js`
And the main `app.js` is automatically calling those components when required.

Comment: By splitting my code the page is taking much longer to load as all of the components are fetched in turn. Do you know of a way to preload all of the required scripts for a certain page?

Comment: I saved around 2mb from loading components like this... but now I'm at 8mb lol... keep in mind I still haven't ran npm run production yet, so I'm hoping it gets a lot lower.

Answer (score 5):

For people that are using Laravel Mix you just need to run `npm run prod` to compress and remove source maps from `app.js` itself.