# How to speed up my .NET core + Vuejs with webpack web app?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-2

I am building a web app in Visual studio and I am using Vuejs for frontend and .NET for backend. I have used webpack as the js bundler . Below is my webpack.config.cs file

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: { main: './App/index.js' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        'scss': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ],
                        'sass': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Vue: ['vue/dist/vue.min.js', 'default'],
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            moment: 'moment',
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.min.js',
            'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery.js'
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        overlay: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    }, output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    ])
}
```

The node modules folder contains vue/dist which has many files namely: vue.common.js, vue.min.js and more.
The output of the file comes in the dist folder present in the wwwroot.

The problem I am facing is the application takes lots of time to load. How to speed up the process? I understand it's related to changing the webpack config, but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: The question is too general. There can be a plenty of reasons why your page is loading too long. Try to read some tutorials for web speed optimization, eg.: https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/engineering/12-techniques-of-website-speed-optimization-performance-testing-and-improvement-practices/  And look also on `optimization` section in webpack config: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/

Comment: @lavor I certainly agree with your point. I have already read  many documentations but still haven;t figured out anything.

Comment: Try to find out what specifically is taking too much time. Is it webpack taking too much time bundling your files? Is it your webserver starting up? Or it might be your webserver serving your Vue app page?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138146/laravel-app-js-very-large-file-size/58572102?noredirect=1#answer-58572102

Comment: @JKL How do to that?